# SweetAlert doesn't wait

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use swal within ajax, but swal do not wait until you make the request, here is my code:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    var data = $("#myForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myURL,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            swal({
                title: "Success",
                text: "Data added.",
                icon: "success"
            })
                .then(() => {
                    window.location.replace(referrer);
                });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that is caused by swal and isn't being executed somewhere else?

Comment: Based on your code, swal will show once the ajax is complete, and the "then" part will execute once you close swal or click swal buttons if any.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any luck reproducing your issue. See the snippet for an example. Are there any errors in the console? Those would be helpful for us to see.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#test');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  fetchTodos()
    .then(() => {
      swal({
        title: 'Success',
        text: "This is in fetchTodos().then()",
        icon: 'success',
      }).then(() => console.log('Do something here'));
    })

});

function fetchTodos() {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">
  SweetAlert
</button>
```

Comment: it does not give an error, it appears for a short time, less than a second and disappears.

Comment: @user3397258 I believe it's because you're tampering with the `window.location` object, and that's causing the window to reload. See this link for more info.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Comment: @user3397258 What happens if you remove the `window.location.replace` code?

Comment: Is the **window.location** object, it work when i remove it.

Comment: @user3397258 What are you trying to do with that line of code?